# Cannot resolve symbol 'SmallTest' Java for android, IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea

I have the same project in both android studio and IntelliJ. For Github reasons, I need the android studio project to work with IntelliJ. However some libraries aren't working in IntelliJ.

`import android.support.test.filters.SmallTest;`

In my java test class this import statement cannot be resolved, meaning I cannot use the @SmallTest notation in my java test class.

In the build.gradle file, I have included these lines:

`androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'`

`androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'`

`testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'`

`testCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'`.

It also cannot resolve any imports for espresso:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
```

Even though I added this line to the build.gradle file:

```
   `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'`
```

I would like to be able to resolve these errors. Could they be due to the fact that I have to use Gradle 2 in IntelliJ because Gradle 3 isn't supported yet? It seems to be the only difference. Thanks